# How to decode json using codeigniter. and In which folder is the main class located?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I am new to codeigniter.

I have been trying to decode a json response in codeigniter. Earlier when i used to code in simple php, I used some CURL functions such as

```
    $init = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($init, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($init, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
    curl_setopt($init, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
    curl_setopt($init, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response = curl_exec($init);
    curl_close($init);
    $abc=json_decode($response,true);
```

I used to get it worked. But In codeigniter how can i decode json string.

**Example :**
**I am trying to display a view with image gallery in codeigniter from a json response. How can i achieve this. I dint find where are the curl functions located ,also the base class**

Please help and lead me to achieve this task.

Comment: You are saying that you were not able to use the above code inside a CodeIgniter project ? Have you tried using it or just assumed ?

Comment: You are decoding the json already. assuming $response contains valid json. What issue are you having? The only thing that could stop it working could be that either $response is not a valid json string. or you do not have CURL setup correctly!

Comment: It simply displays an empty value.. I think json response is returning null.

Comment: do u have curl library in your libraries folder in codeigntier......

Comment: If the above code worked in a normal PHP page, then I don't see any issue running in a CodeIgniter project ! Debug the code and see whether you are supplying the correct url or not.

Comment: @Venkat I dint find curl library

Comment: may be thats the problem search for curl library in google and load that in your controller..........before calling that

Comment: You can find curl in this link https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-curl

Comment: @AkhileshBChandran actually i was expecting curl library or some sought of classes already created for such task. Since I heard Codeigniter will make php coding simpler. I also dont expect that, Everything should be made simple. So let me have a try..

Comment: hey Rama try after u inserted curl library in your application library folder and let me know...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20092/discussion-between-venkat-and-rama-raju-dantuluri)

Comment: Yes it worked @Venkat. Thank you so much Boss. Also i appreciate AkhileshBChandran for such simple words, Which made me realize where i am going wrong. Thank you very much guys. Great support From you.

Comment: hey Rama wrote the answer. please accept it. Any time if you want help.

Comment: hey r u working in PHP domain. I think you may be from India.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because you may not have curl library in your codeIgntier libraries. So get curl library from this link and try your code after loading it in your controller function.

https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-curl

Comment: hey rama r u free to chat for 10 minutes with me

Comment: I am not familiar with chat in stackoverflow. So far i dint used it